# Maven Depedency build has different version for build

Tags: maven-2

We have a Java application that refers 1.14 version of an artifactId . Now the same application has a dependency to a different application which refers the same artifactId but of a different version. Though we can manually change them to refer to one but it requires due manual operation:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyyyyy</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.1</version>
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa</groupId>
        <artifactId>zzzzzz</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The 2.0 version refers to a same artificat but of different version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyyyyy</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</parent>
```

As such though build is successful but deployment and execution fails.

Other than manual updation how can we technically resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the `<parent>` tag, is this a multi-module project? If so, shouldn't the `<parent>` pom `<version>` of the two modules be the same?

Comment: Yes it is a multi-module project. Our objective is that the dependency / main application can be build separately also. So only when the main application is being build we need to verify that both modules refer to same artifactid version. Even though if we overrule that i.e. dependency application will not be build separately - we still land up using two pom.xml - how can we synchronize the version across automatically. Is there a process for the same ensuring it to override manual mistakes?